# Export from Power BI into Excel but keep all formats/visuals the same

Tags: powerbi

Good morning,
I've created a dashboard in Power BI, launched it internally but I also want this to replace reports but the team need to be able to amend some columns or add in annotations.

Is there a way of being able to export the whole thing into Excel, keeping the visuals as they are and the data?

I've used the Export to Excel for the whole view but it only exports the underlying data as a pivot but If I Export as a PP etc then my tables are missing data as it's only showing the snapshot image

Comment: No, it not possible to export everything fully to excel. It will only connect to the data model as a pivot table. You can't use power bi to amend data, you would have to have some sort of power app to write back. You can however in the service allow comments, but you need to be clear by what you mean by annotations

Comment: Thank you. At least I know it can't be done. We send out reports so would look to use Power BI for reporting rather than creating from scratch in Excel and producing all the analysis (graphs etc). We have built the dashboard/reporting replacements in BI but we would need to add comments for clients or charges etc last minute prior to sending to clients and not all clients want or need to use BI so I was looking at workaround's to save us time whilst utilising BI. Thanks for your response.